# Automated mails from a documentation on a closed network through adsl to user emails

Tags: security, smtp

I have a closed network that has a documentation system that sends automated emails to users using smtp. The users are all on the same exchange server.  We have an adsl connection. Are there security issues if I open port 25 outgoing.? And if so can I limit it to communication with the specified exchange server?

Comment: There are a lot of details left out concerning network design and what is being used as a firewall, but I believe the question can be answered in general terms to your satisfaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you limit SMTP to allow outbound only, then no, there are no security concerns as far as an unsolicited inbound connection exploiting an unpatched / vulnerable system.

Without knowing what your firewall is, I will go out on a fairly sturdy limb and say "yes", you can create a firewall rule that only allows port 25 inbound communication to go to the Exchange server. That is in fact a common thing to do to secure email communication and prevent inbound / outbound SMTP tomfoolery. In fact, if your systems are closed and predictable enough, you can create firewall rules that only allow outbound / inbound email to and from the two email server systems. Of course, this gets tricky depending on how email clients access the server and if they too are expected to communicate through email, but a deeper discussion of that kind of network design will require more information about your specific network.